# Rails Ransack - How to include multiple conditions with a ransacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

I am trying to create a Ransack section for our search page that will look across a student's grade table and find students within a range for each kind of grade.

Given: Student has_many Grades and Grade belongs_to Category

I want a form section like:
Biology Grade grater than [ 2 ]
Math Grade grater than [ 3 ]

Eventually something like: `SELECT... WHERE (grade.value >= 2 AND grade.category_id = 1) AND (grade.value >= 3 AND grade.category_id = 2)`

Any ideas on how to set that up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to build condition groupings. Take a look at https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/helpers/form_builder.rb#L74 and follow the code. The Ransack demo application is also a good resource.

It's a shame that Ransack does not have a comprehensive documentation. I spent a whole day trying to make similar feature work.

Try something like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'q[c]', 'or' %>
<% Category.each_with_index do |category, i| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "q[g][#{i}][m]", 'and' %>
  <%= text_field_tag "q[g][#{i}][c][0]", 'grades_value_gteq' %>
  <%= text_field_tag "q[g][#{i}][c][1]", 'grades_category_eq' %>
<% end %>
```

You are building groupings of conditions inside Ransack. Inside each you join the conditions with AND and then join the groups with OR.

Comment: Wow, I dug around in the source for hours and totally missed that! I ended up making some kludgey ransacker and predicate combos, but this is much cleaner. I really hope that one day someone who deeply understands Ransack writes up docs, it could be so good for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    Grade greater than
    <%= f.text_field :grades_value_gteq %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    Grade category is
    <%= f.text_field :grades_category_eq #change this eventually to a collection dropdown %>   
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the goal was to have several grade-category pairs on a single form so they would be combined into a single query. This would only find one pair. This may be impossible with Ransack if it requires a subquery for each grade-category pair and then a join of all students with id's in each of the results. Thank you for your answer though.